# REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING when trying to access the Salesforce API with beatbox

Tags: api, soap, python

I am using [`beatbox`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beatbox/32.1) to access the SOAP API of Salesforce. More specifically, I am trying to convert a `Lead` using `convertLead` like so

```
# Assuming soap_client is a PythonClient already logged in and
# lead is a Lead object.

response = soap_client.convertLead({
    'leadId': lead.pk,
    'convertedStatus': "Qualified - converted",
})
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_convertlead.htm) this endpoint should not need any more parameter than `leadId` and `convertedStatus`, however the response contains the following error message

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing:
>   [Company_Name__c]: [Company_Name__c] (System
>   Code)UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION00Qg0000003Er0pEACfalse

It is good to mention that `lead` (the `Lead` object to be converted) actually contains a non empty `Company` field.

Any idea of what could cause this error message? I tried to specifically add a `companyName` field to the API call but it did not help.

Comment: seems Company_Name__c is a custom field on your account object which is marked as required in the field settings. either remove the required option on this field or populate it and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with your API access or the provided code. The reason is as VamsiKrishna said your custom field. You can't fix the error by adding something to this single API call.

You should try to find out on which object this field exists. From just seeing the error, it could be either Account, Contact or Opportunity - but likely it's Account. You can find it at clickpath:

Setup > Customize > Leads > Fields - there scroll down a bit to the list "Lead Custom Fields & Relationships" and press the "Map Lead Fields" button.

Next step you should figure why this field exists at all. The person who created the mapping and the field (as mandatory) should have had good reason to do so. If this reason does no longer apply, remove the required option.

If your processes are still requiring this field you can find the lead custom field at "Map Lead Fields" which acts as the source field. Now before your conversion call, you could check with an additional API call if the source field is populated for the lead you are about to convert and do the conversion only then.